# restore elastic search snapshot from 2.3.0 to 5.6.0

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to restore elastic search backup from 2.3.0 to 5.6.0

Following the below steps:

1. update elasticsearch.yml file.

Added **path.repo: ["C:/backup_elasticsearch_2_3_0"]**

2. Run below command for backup from postman

   a. PUT localhost:9200/_snapshot/eventindexbackup

   {
          "type": "fs", 
          "settings": {
              "location": "eventindex",
              "compress": "true"
          } }

   b. PUT localhost:9200/_snapshot/eventindexbackup/22aug18

   {
          "indices": "event*",
          "ignore_unavailable": true,
          "include_global_state": false }

   c. To check, backup is created or not:

   GET localhost:9200/_snapshot/eventindexbackup/22aug18
3. Stop the elastic search.
4. Download the elastic search 5.6.0
5. updated elasticsearch.yml file.

Added **path.repo: ["C:/backup_elasticsearch_2_3_0"]**

started it.

6. run this query from postman

POST localhost:9200/_snapshot/eventindexbackup/22aug18/_restore

I am getting below error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "repository_missing_exception",
                "reason": "[eventindexbackup] missing"
            }
        ],
        "type": "repository_missing_exception",
        "reason": "[eventindexbackup] missing"
    },
    "status": 404`enter code here`
}
```

Do I need to create the snapshot in 5.6.0 elastic search?
Am I following the wrong steps? Please provide me the correct steps.

Comment: I assume the new instance v5.6.0 is a new cluster. You need to register the repository - the yaml setting alone is not sufficient. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/modules-snapshots.html